# Filter query with Storyblok

Tags: nuxt.js, storyblok

I try to fetch stories and apply filters on them.
However I end up on a problem. According to the result data I get,
I believe that filter_query params are connected with OR operator.
My query looks something like this:

```
const storyblokApi = useStoryblokApi()
const { data: realty, pending } = await useAsyncData<Realty>(
    async () => await storyblokApi.get(cdn/stories, {
        version: "published",
        content_type: "project",
        per_page: 6,
        filter_query: {
            price: {
                "gt-int": 0,
                "lt-int": 1300001,
            },
            area: { in_array: "Dubai Marina,Blue Waters" },
            market: { in_array: "primary" },
        }
    })
)
```

The result is stories (projects) who have area of Dubai Marina and Blue Waters however "Blue Waters" has market:"secondary" and should not be. I expect to have only projects of Dubai Marina who have market:"primary", and projects of area:"Blue Waters" not to be added.

I also noticed that if i change the order of the filter params I get different results

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no operator `in_array` so it will be ignored. According to the docs there are two operators for arrays called `any_in_array` and `all_in_array`.

https://www.storyblok.com/docs/api/content-delivery/v2#filter-queries/operation-any-in-array